# Popping or dismissing a ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, dismiss

I have a Feedback View Controller that is accessed in 7 locations across 4 different screens.

One way it's presented in a `navigationController` via `pushViewController`. The other 6 times it's presented modally.

Here's the function that opens the Feedback VC's

```
struct Constants{
    static func openFeedback(openFrom: UIViewController, nav:Bool) {
        let fbStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "FeedbackViewController", bundle: nil)
        let fbVC = fbStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FBSBID")
        fbVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        fbVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        if nav {
            openFrom.navigationController?.pushViewController(fbVC, animated: true)
        } else {
            openFrom.present(fbVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

The Feedback VC is called with either `Constants.openFeedback(openFrom: self, nav: true)` or `Constants.openFeedback(openFrom: self, nav: false)`

*Opening the VC works just fine!*

Here's my close button on the Feedback View Controller:

```
@IBAction func closeButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Which works 6 out of the 7 times, when not in the navigation stack. When it's in the navigation stack, the close button does not do anything.

**My question is, how do I close out of the Feedback View Controller, based on if it's in the navigationController stack or not?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check if view controller is embedded inside `UINavigationController` by checking if controller's `navigationController` is `nil` or not.

So if it is embedded you can use `popViewController(animated:)` on navigation controller to "dismiss" pushed controller

```
if let navCon = navigationController {
    navCon.popViewController(animated: true)
} else {
    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```